# error: address of overloaded function with no contextual type information

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Code:

```
class que {
public:
    que operator++(int) {}  // 1
    que &operator++() {}
    que &operator+=(int n) {
        que& (que::*go)();
        go = 0; if(n > 0) go = &que::operator++ ; // 2
        //go = (n > 0) ?    (&que::operator++) : 0 ;    // 3
    }
};

int main() {
    que iter;
    iter += 3;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to replace line 2 by line 3("if" statement for "?:").
If I uncomment 3, compiler gives me an error.
If I delete line 1, then line 3 works.
Question is: **what does compiler want from me**?
Error: error: address of overloaded function with no contextual type information
Compiler: gcc-4.5.2

Comment: why do you need to use a function pointer here ? Why not just call `operator++` repeatedly ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> error: address of overloaded function with no contextual type information

There are two functions with the `operator++` name (that's the 'overloaded function' bit of the message), you need to specify which one you want (that's the 'contextual type information' one):

```
n > 0 ? (que& (que::*)())&que::operator++ : 0
```

You have to consider that the above subexpression is independent from the enclosing full expression, the assignment to `go`. So it must be correct on its own, i.e. it can't use the type of `go` to pick the correct overload because it's not part of this particular subexpression.

Comment: I thought it can get this info from "go" declaration.