# How to put min and max inside a function

Tags: c++

I'd like to do this piece of code

```cpp
auto f = player == color ? max : min;
```

Where `player` and `color` are booleans and `min` and `max` are standard functions from C++ library.

But I get this error : `error: overloaded function with no contextual type information`

How do I tell the compiler I want to load min and max that compares integers?

Here's how to reproduce the error :

1) create a file toto.cpp

2) paste this :

```cpp
int main() {
   bool one = 1;
   bool zero = 0;
   auto f = one == zero ? std::min : std::max;
   return 0;
}
```

3) compile it `g++ toto.cpp`

4) run it `./a.out`

5) observe the same error as above

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE], but before you do, [please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304926/overloaded-function-with-no-contextual-type-information-cannot-resolve-overloa) [use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55355715/how-do-i-solve-overloaded-function-with-no-contextual-type-information-error) [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121196/error-address-of-overloaded-function-with-no-contextual-type-information) [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38045634/template-function-cast-address-of-overloaded-function-with-no-contextual-type-i), thanks!

Comment: `warning: code example with too little context`

Comment: Your question is off on one point: `min` and `max` are not *functions* from the standard library; they are function *templates*.

Comment: `min` and `max` are not functions. They're function **templates**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
   auto Max = [](int a, int b){return std::max(a, b);};
   auto Min = [](int a, int b){return std::min(a, b);};

   bool one = 1;
   bool zero = 0;
   auto f = one == zero ? Min : Max;
   return 0;
}
```

I think the compiler is simply not able to deduce the template parameter(s) for std::max and std::min when you write it like:

```
auto f = one == zero ? std::min : std::max;
```